Can I add css-vars to the Iris colour picker?
I have some css-vars in my, well, css:
--clr-background:#f8f8f8;
--clr-text:#000;
--clr-accent:#b91023;

Can I add them as a palette to the Iris colour picker, but in a way that I get the name when selected?
To be clearer: if the User selects rgb(0,0,0) themself he wants that, but if he selects the clr-text, he wants that theme variable which only happens to be black currently.
